Fill gap between stucco wall and light fixture
I installed a rectangle shaped patio light on the wall. The light has a flat back and because it's a stucco wall the light doesn't sit flush against the wall. How can fill the gap to help prevent bugs from getting behind the light. The gap is about 1/8" to 3/16". I have silicon sealant for the top to stop water from getting behind it.


"Compriband" tape.

It's adhesive closed cell foam tape. It is sold in compressed form. When unrolled and applied, it will slowly expand over a few hours to about 3-4x the compressed thickness. It's intended for the gap between window frame and masonry. It can fill quite large gaps and doesn't need to be squished tight like the usual foam sealant tape for doors etc, since it will simply expand to fill the gap.

Will push the light away from the wall when it becomes uncompressed? Would a backer rod also work? I'm assuming something is needed for the sealant to attach to.

No it's very soft. Backer rod is much stiffer. Indeed you would need the back of the light to be flat to apply the tape.

Thanks for the info! Any chance this is sold under a different name in the states? I keep finding UK distributors for it.

hmm... maybe "Precompressed foam sealant"
